# Don't know how to fix a broken Python installation

Tags: python, windows, installation, mysql-connector

I was trying to install a SQL-Python connector and kept receiving an error that it could not find the python installation. It said that it only accepted the version used by the installer from the python website so I downloaded that and tried to install it in the same path where my python was (C:\Python38) but then saw that it was installing a 32-bit version of python there so I cancelled the install mid-install (this was a mistake). I think I did that at the wrong time because now the folder still exists but it had deleted some parts of my python installation. So now I'm in a weird place where I can't install python (When I open the 64-bit installer it only gives me the [option to Modify, Repair or Uninstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWCNh.png), and all of those shoot up errors where it says that it can't find the python installation). The 32-bit version does allow me to try and install but I get an error saying "The File 'python.dll' cannot be installed because the file cannot be found in cabinet file 'cab1.cab.'"

If I try and uninstall python from the Windows uninstaller I also [get errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BF6mx.png) that there is no python version to install.

I tried just deleting [the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cudep.png) from my system but that doesn't work either. Not sure how to bring my computer back to a state where I can do a fresh python install. Is there any way?

Comment: What happens when you try to delete the folder?

Answer (score 2):

What I did, and I am not sure that it was the cause of solving the problem, was to delete the 'python.exe' and 'python3.exe' files that where in 'C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps'. As the user don't have access to delete them from the files explorer, I entered from cmd as administrator and deleted them with the 'del' command.
Again I am not sure if that was the cause but I think it worked for me while I was trying to delete all python related files to reinstall.